# Null pointer Exception when autowired class is called

Tags: spring-boot, testng

```
@Component
public class car {
    void getCar(){
        System.out.println("Honda");

    }
}



public class Tyre  {
    @Autowired
    private car cars;
    @Test
    void print(){

            cars.getCar();
        }
    }
```

[image]

java.lang.NullPointerException when "cars.getcar" is called
Spring Version 2.7.1
I am trying to annotate an autowire for Car.class
but it returns null on run time
Attached the project Structure

Answer (score 0):

add `@SpringBootTest` on top of the test class.

```
    @SpringBootTest
    public class Tyre  {
        @Autowired
        private car cars;
    
        @Test
        void print(){
            cars.getCar();
        }
```

Comment: Still getting same error